# How do I animate the alpha of a series of html canvas paths?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm looking to create a simple animation loop using html canvas. Each path(or triangle) is intended to fade-in in sequence and then fade-out in the same sequence. I've found a great deal of resources around animating with motion, but not with alpha and especially not animating paths in succession within canvas. Any ideas?

**Disclaimer:** This is my first foray into using canvas, and my javascript knowledge is shoddy. Since I'm using the same shape, I'm going to figure out how to replicate, rotate and translate the original as a separate learning.

**Update 1:** To track my progress, [here is a link to my sandbox](http://leegentrydesign.com/test-area/loader.html).

**Update 2:** I changed the structure of the script to give me more control over each path.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('loader');

if (elem && elem.getContext) {

var ctxYellow = elem.getContext('2d');
var ctxOrange = elem.getContext('2d');
var ctxRed = elem.getContext('2d');
var ctxViolet = elem.getContext('2d');
var ctxBlue = elem.getContext('2d');

// Yellow triangle
if (ctxYellow) {
    ctxYellow.fillStyle = '#f5ab1c';
    ctxYellow.beginPath();
    ctxYellow.moveTo(150, 150);
    ctxYellow.lineTo(20, 75);
    ctxYellow.lineTo(150, 0);
    ctxYellow.lineTo(150, 150);
    ctxYellow.fill();
    ctxYellow.closePath();
}

// Orange triangle
if (ctxOrange) {
    ctxOrange.fillStyle = '#f26d23';
    ctxOrange.beginPath();
    ctxOrange.moveTo(150, 150);
    ctxOrange.lineTo(150, 0);
    ctxOrange.lineTo(280, 75);
    ctxOrange.lineTo(150, 150);
    ctxOrange.fill();
    ctxOrange.closePath();
}

// Red triangle
if (ctxRed) {
    ctxRed.fillStyle = '#cd1f44';
    ctxRed.beginPath();
    ctxRed.moveTo(150, 150);
    ctxRed.lineTo(280, 75);
    ctxRed.lineTo(280, 225);
    ctxRed.lineTo(150, 150);
    ctxRed.fill();
    ctxRed.closePath();
}

// Violet triangle
if (ctxViolet) {
    ctxViolet.fillStyle = '#851a54';
    ctxViolet.beginPath();
    ctxViolet.moveTo(150, 150);
    ctxViolet.lineTo(280, 225);
    ctxViolet.lineTo(150, 300);
    ctxViolet.lineTo(150, 150);
    ctxViolet.fill();
    ctxViolet.closePath();
}

// Blue triangle
if (ctxBlue) {
    ctxBlue.fillStyle = '#295a9c';
    ctxBlue.beginPath();
    ctxBlue.moveTo(150, 150);
    ctxBlue.lineTo(150, 300);
    ctxBlue.lineTo(20, 225);
    ctxBlue.lineTo(150, 150);
    ctxBlue.fill();
    ctxBlue.closePath();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `save`/`load` methods?

Comment: I haven't. But I'm not sure why I'd want to.

Comment: If you want to animate something, having no other objects, then you'll be enough with clearRect. Otherwise, they may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I kind of cheated. I ended up using jQuery. Here's what I came out with:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('yellow');

if (elem && elem.getContext) {
var ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(245,171,28,1)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(150,150);
    ctx.lineTo(20,75);
    ctx.lineTo(150,0);
    ctx.lineTo(150,150);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

var elem = document.getElementById('orange');

if (elem && elem.getContext) {
var ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(242,109,35,1)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(150,150);
    ctx.lineTo(150,0);
    ctx.lineTo(280,75);
    ctx.lineTo(150,150);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

var elem = document.getElementById('red');

if (elem && elem.getContext) {
var ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(205,31,68,1)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(150,150);
    ctx.lineTo(280,75);
    ctx.lineTo(280,225);
    ctx.lineTo(150,150);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
 }

var elem = document.getElementById('violet');

if (elem && elem.getContext) {
var ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(133,26,84,1)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(150,150);
    ctx.lineTo(280,225);
    ctx.lineTo(150,300);
    ctx.lineTo(150,150);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

var elem = document.getElementById('blue');

if (elem && elem.getContext) {
var ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(41,90,156,1)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(150, 150);
    ctx.lineTo(150, 300);
    ctx.lineTo(20, 225);
    ctx.lineTo(150, 150);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

$(function() {
var timer = null;

var anim = function() {
    $.each([yellow, orange, red, violet, blue], function(i, el) {
        $('.color' + (i + 1)).delay(100 * i).fadeIn();
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        $.each([yellow, orange, red, violet, blue], function(i, el) {
            $('.color' + (i + 1)).delay(100 * i).fadeOut();
        });
    }, 1500);

    if (!timer) {
        return timer = setInterval(anim, 3000);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

anim();

})
```

I made separate canvases for each path, absolutely positioned them, and animated them with jQuery. Thanks for the advice! It helped.

**Update:** My roommate walked me through some improvements to clean up the code and make it run smoother. I still can't get this to work in Firefox, though.

Answer (score 0):

you're alomst there. first: you can **NOT** have multiple contexts at the same time for the same canvas node! either use multiple canvas-nodes stacked on top of each other or change the color after `closePath()` and before `beginPath`. That's actually what you are doing anyways, only that you used 5 variables for it where one is sufficient.

alpha can be animated with this:

```
var ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.4;
```

again, like the color this can be done during you animation though that will change the overall alpha value (not sure that's the right approach). I'd advice using `rgba()` values for `fillStyle` instead. basically you need to translate your color definition from hey to rgb values and then add a value from 0 to 1 for the alpha value. google hex to rgba for generators.

PS: check out the W3C spec for more info: http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/